# Probability of a boolean formula which use only xor and and operations

Tags: probability, boolean

Can I obtain the probability formula from a boolean formula only translating `and` operator by the `multiplication` operator; and the `xor` operator by the `sum` operator?

For example Pr[(a and b) xor c = 1] = Pr[a=1]*Pr[b=1]+Pr[c=1]?

EDIT

In case no, are there any general rules to get the probability expression using the boolean formula? (Suppose events totally independent)

Comment: Is $Pr[(a \text{ and } a) = 1] = (Pr[a=1])^2$?

Comment: no because a and a = a then $Pr[(a \text{ and } a) = 1] = (Pr[a=1])$

Comment: Have you ever heard of "independent events" in the context of probability?  How about mutually exclusive events?

Comment: The punchline is that $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)$ is true if *and only if* $A$ and $B$ are independent events.  In general, you should always suspect events are dependent unless you have strong reason to believe otherwise.  The correct generic formula is $\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A)\times \Pr(B\mid A)$ where this term on the right is a conditional probability.  Similarly, $\Pr(A\cup B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)$ is also incorrect and is true if and only if $A$ and $B$ have trivial intersection (*either by having completely empty intersection or by having their intersection be probability zero event*).

Comment: The correct statement is $\Pr(A\cup B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$.  Intersections are analogous to `and`'s and unions are analogous to `or`'s.  Now... you talk about `xor` instead of `or`... that follows similarly but here the correct statement is $\Pr(A\Delta B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-2\Pr(A\cap B)$, the symmetric difference operator $\Delta$ being analogous to `xor`.  Note that given two non-trivial events if they are independent they will *not* have trivial intersection, and if they have trivial intersection they are not independent.